# How to extract all the characters including linefeeds(\n) from a given string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-group

I have a string in the below format : **Please note : \n means linefeed**

> \n\nThe following table provides the details of intangible assets\nacquired, by major class and weighted average useful life:\n\n \n\n(USS in millions)                                       USEFUL LIFE\nCustomer relationships                                    15 years        $265\nIntellectual property                                      10 years          120\nTrade names                                               15 years           51\nFavorable leases                                            38 years            26\nOther                                                    various             2\nTotal intangible assets                                                     $464\n\nThe fair value in the opening balance sheet of the 30%\nredeemable noncontrolling interest in Loders was estimated to\nbe $450 million.

I have to extract all the characters between **\n\n \n\n** and **\n\n**

**Expected output :**

> (USS in millions)                                       USEFUL LIFE\nCustomer relationships                                    15 years        $265\nIntellectual property                                      10 years          120\nTrade names                                               15 years           51\nFavorable leases                                            38 years            26\nOther                                                    various             2\nTotal intangible assets                                                     $464

I have written a logic as below :

> re.findall(r'(\n\n\s\n\n)(.|\n)*(\n\n)', result)

But above code is not giving me desired result. Can somebody help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first match the double newline (or match an optional carriage return and newline) and then capture all lines in group 1 that end with a newline and don't start with a newline.

Using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), you will get back a list with the capturing groups values. The desired result is the second item.

```
\r?\n\r?\n(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*)\r?\n\r?\n
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EkaqPY/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QLda8d)

```
import re

s="\n\nThe following table provides the details of intangible assets\nacquired, by major class and weighted average useful life:\n\n \n\n(USS in millions) USEFUL LIFE\nCustomer relationships 15 years $265\nIntellectual property 10 years 120\nTrade names 15 years 51\nFavorable leases 38 years 26\nOther various 2\nTotal intangible assets $464\n\nThe fair value in the opening balance sheet of the 30%\nredeemable noncontrolling interest in Loders was estimated to\nbe $450 million."

regex = r"\r?\n\r?\n(.*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n).*)*)\r?\n\r?\n"

print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
[
'The following table provides the details of intangible assets\nacquired, by major class and weighted average useful life:', 
'(USS in millions) USEFUL LIFE\nCustomer relationships 15 years $265\nIntellectual property 10 years 120\nTrade names 15 years 51\nFavorable leases 38 years 26\nOther various 2\nTotal intangible assets $464'
]
```

Comment: Hi fourth bird, this solution does not generate the expected output. Please help me getting the required output from above question. The ** (double asterisk) mark was added to make the expected output bold but somehow that did not work. I have removed it from question.

Comment: @ChampRJ Can you try it like this? https://regex101.com/r/EkaqPY/1 ? Is the text in the regex demo the right outline with all the newlines? I get a result with re.findall. https://ideone.com/ebofMe

Comment: Yes, your second solution seems to serve the purpose. Can you please help with how can I use this with Python as I don't know for some reason Python is giving me "None" as output. Thanks for quick response though!!

Comment: You can check this Python example https://ideone.com/QLda8d I will update the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220575/discussion-between-champrj-and-the-fourth-bird).